# How to install the new GNOME Software app on 16.04 for testing purposes?

Tags: software-installation, software-center, testing, 16.04, gnome-software

**PLEASE NOTE:** This Q&A has been archived and is now for historical reference **only**. For more information on this, see answer.

---

On my system running Ubuntu 16.04 I am wanting to test the new upcoming Ubuntu Software Center called GNOME Software which is set to replace the current Ubuntu Software Center in 16.04, however only the old Ubuntu Software Center is currently installed on 16.04 by default, so how can I get the new one to test it?

Comment: Just a note: Self answers with bug workarounds aren't the nuisance bug report questions we usually close that way.  They are generally encouraged as temporary work-arounds, if I remember correctly, for users.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**PLEASE NOTE:** What is said in the answer below was only true for a short period in the early development of 16.04 (and was only useful for practical purposes in that period), this Q&A has been kept only for historical reference. You will also see that the question has been closed with the close reason of `...was only relevant to a very specific period of time.`, and that I was the first to cast such a close vote.

`gnome-software` is now included in 16.04 which has been released and there is no need to install it from this PPA, which may not even be in existence any more. So as I previously stated, please only use this answer for historical reference, **do not** do as it says.

---

It is currently currently only available for install via a [PPA](https://askubuntu.com/questions/4983/what-are-ppas-and-how-do-i-use-them) ([the GNOME Software PPA](https://launchpad.net/~ubuntu-desktop/+archive/ubuntu/gnome-software)), in order to add the PPA to your system run:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-desktop/gnome-software
sudo apt-get update
```

And then to install GNOME Software run:

```
sudo apt-get install gnome-software packagekit
```

<s>In order to fetch, populate and update the information in the app you may need to download [this script](http://people.canonical.com/~laney/random-scripts/appstream.sh) and then `cd` into the directory it downloaded into (most likely `~/Downloads`) with:</s>

<s>`cd ~/Downloads`</s>

<s>Make it executable with:</s>

<s>`chmod +x appstream.sh`</s>

<s>Then execute it as root with:</s>

<s>`sudo ./appstream.sh`</s>

(The reason the above instructions are crossed out is because that method was only necessary for a short period of time (until they configured the `gnome-software` application to do that itself), you are no longer required to do so, but the text was kept and not removed for the reasons of historical archiving.)

For further reference [please read this article](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2016/01/test-new-ubuntu-16-04-software-center).